# Java Script Multiple Redirects Based on Input

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am somewhat familiar with html but am not with java script I am wondering if there is a way to have a form with say for example a name field and based on the name that is input to the field use java script to redirect to an html page for that person.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Redirect Form</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>Name:</p><input type="name" id="name">
            <p>E-mail</p><input type="email" id="inputEmail"><br>
            <br>
            <button type="button">Redirect</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

So I have this and i want to type in the name "John" in the name field and have it redirect to a page named john.html or if i type in the name "mary" have it redirect to a page named mary. I dont want to generate pages for each name this will be for the two specific names that will have their pages created beforehand. How do i create the java script to handle that for me?

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution but can show you the way of doing it.

```js
var input_link;
function fetchInput() {
  input_link = $('#name').val();
}

function redirect() {
  fetchInput();
  window.location.href = 'http://example.com/'+input_link+'.html';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name:</p><input type="name" id="name">
<p>E-mail</p><input type="email" id="inputEmail"><br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="redirect();">Redirect</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an onclick even to the button like so.

```
document.getElementById("{buttonID}").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "www.yoursite.com/" + 
        document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
};
```

Make sure you give your HTML button element an id, and then replace "{buttonID}" in the code with that id value. Do the same thing for the name input field (give it an id and replace "textbox_id" with that input id value).

Also, don't use `<p>` for input labels. There's a specific element for that purpose, `<label>`. And you don't need `type=button` on the button element (that's redundant). So the complete html would look like:

```
<label for="name">Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label>
<label for="email">Email:<input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail"></label>
<button id="submit">Redirect</button>
```